# Excel : How to count occurrence of particular color ( Green ) in a Row?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-udf

I want to count number of occurrence of a word in the excel in green color. For Example my excel is looks like this :-

[image: Snil of my excel worksheet]

I want to calculate occurrence of Green (X) and Red (X).

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible in Excel. You will need VBA / a user defined function.

Answer (score 2):

You will need VBA / a user defined function.
Following [this tutorial](http://www.exceltrick.com/how_to/sum-cells-based-on-background-color/):

> 1. First of all open your worksheet where you need to add the cells based on background colors.
> 2. Next, press ALT + F11 to open the VB Editor. Navigate to ‘Insert’ > ‘Module’.
> 3. After this, paste the “ColorIndex” UDF in the Editor.

```
Function ColorIndex(CellColor As Range)  
ColorIndex = CellColor.Interior.ColorIndex  
End Function
```

You can then use ColorIndex(*cellReference*) in your Excel sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should change your point of view. Instead of colores "X"s, you could change the letter to "y", for example.
So the  COUNTIF would work.